# Cloud function to load json file to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We need to upload one json file into cloud bucket and then we need to write a cloud function which can load json file data into bigquery table.

Comment: Please provide something that you have tried. The questions seems to be quite abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an official documentation about

[Streaming data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions)

> In the preceding diagram, the pipeline consists of the following
> steps:
>
> 1.JSON files are uploaded to the FILES_SOURCE Cloud Storage bucket.
>
> 2.This event triggers the streaming Cloud Function.
>
> 3.Data is parsed and inserted into BigQuery.
>
> 4.The ingestion status is logged into Firestore and Cloud Logging.
>
> 5.A message is published in one of the following Pub/Sub topics: streaming_success_topic streaming_error_topic
>
> 6.Depending on the results, Cloud Functions moves the JSON file from the
> FILES_SOURCE bucket to one of the following buckets: FILES_ERROR
> FILES_SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Dataflow Google-provided templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates), the template [Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery) is a batch pipeline that allows you to read text files stored in Cloud Storage, transform them using a JavaScript User Defined Function (UDF) that you provide, and output the result to BigQuery.

You will need to fit the UDF function to your use case.